# Active style on anchor parent list object

Tags: html, css

With pure css, I am trying to change the color of a list element based on the child anchor selected if is it active, but not achieving this. My code is:

```css
body > div > div.col-md-2.tabNav {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.col-md-2.tabNav > ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.col-md-2.tabNav > ul > p, .col-md-2.tabNav > ul > li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.col-md-2.tabNav > ul > li:active, .col-md-2.tabNav > ul > li:focus, .col-md-2.tabNav > ul > li:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 tabNav">
    <ul class="tabTitle">
        <p>Project tools</p>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#/home">Welcome</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Experiments</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Interview Notes</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="tabTitle">
        <p>Hypothesis worksheets</p>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="/#/steps">Problem phase</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="/#/solutionHyp">Solution phase</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Service phase</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Growth phase</a></li>                
    </ul>            
</div>
```

Not sure why the active or focus isn't taking, but the hover is. Thoughts?

Also, based on my selector, can't I combine in pure css the active, focus, hover rather than separating via comma?

Thanks much.

Comment: IDK if i'm getting it right. The :active selector occurs when you click on the item, and keep your finger over the mouse button, but as soon as you lift the finger up the effect is gone. That been said, you want an active state that remains even if the mouse button is not being pressed anymore?

Comment: Apply it to the `a` child of the `li`, not to the `li`. https://jsfiddle.net/1mmtqkqe/

Comment: @TylerH - that does not effect the background-color of the <li> itself.

Comment: @Mark No, but it shouldn't be too important which element's background color you change, since it's most likely the effect you're looking for, and not those specific implementation details.

Comment: @TylerH - what I am saying is that the entire li element is not highlighted when active with this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Both `active` and `focus` would apply to the `a` tag, not to `li`, as you wrote it. (as pseudo selectors, that is)